# Column does not exist when querying Rosetta endpoint

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

I'm currently running `cardano-node` version 1.35.0 and `rosetta-server` 1.8.2. The node is synced and I have blocks in postgres, however each query to rosetta throws an error:

```
curl -vvv -X POST 'http://<node-url>:8080/network/status' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"network_identifier": {"blockchain": "cardano", "network": "mainnet"}}' | jq

{
  "code": 5000,
  "message": "An error occurred",
  "retriable": true,
  "details": {
    "message": "An error occurred for request 9149: column b.previous_id does not exist"
  }
}
```

The log shows an issue with the query, specifically the join.

```
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z 2022-12-13 21:50:05.011 UTC [11737] postgres@cexplorer STATEMENT:
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z    SELECT
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.hash as hash,
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.block_no as number,
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      (b.time at time zone 'utc') as "createdAt",
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      CASE
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        WHEN b2.block_no IS NOT NULL THEN b2.block_no
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        WHEN b3.block_no IS NOT NULL THEN b3.block_no
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        ELSE 0
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      END AS "previousBlockNumber",
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      CASE
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        WHEN b2.block_no IS NOT NULL THEN b2.hash
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        WHEN b3.block_no IS NOT NULL THEN b3.hash
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        WHEN b.block_no = 1 THEN b3.hash -- block 1
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z {"level":50,"time":1670968205012,"pid":125,"hostname":"coin-node-ada-kilo-coin-node-ada-kilo-0","reqId":8544,"length":112,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"42703","position":"684","file":"parse_relation.c","line":"3393","routine":"errorMissingColumn","msg":"[errorHandler] An error ocurred and will be sent as response","stack":"error: column b.previous_id does not exist\n    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/cardano-rosetta-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)\n    at Parser.handlePacket (/cardano-rosetta-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)\n    at Parser.parse (/cardano-rosetta-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/cardano-rosetta-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)\n    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)\n    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)","type":"Error","v":1}
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z        ELSE b.hash -- genesis
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      END AS "previousBlockHash",
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.tx_count as "transactionsCount",
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      s.description as "createdBy",
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.size as size,
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.epoch_no as "epochNo",
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.slot_no as "slotNo"
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z    FROM
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      block b
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      LEFT JOIN slot_leader s ON b.slot_leader_id = s.id
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      LEFT JOIN block b2 ON b.previous_id = b2.id
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      LEFT JOIN block b3 ON b2.previous_id = b3.id
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z    WHERE
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      b.block_no = $1 AND
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z      $2 = $2
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z    LIMIT 1
2022-12-13T21:50:05Z null
```

I'm using this Dockerfile: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-rosetta/blob/master/Dockerfile

I have tried syncing from scratch to no avail. Not sure what else I can do to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by re-running the db migration `cardano-db-tool run-migrations --mdir /cardano-db-sync/schema/`